# Defect version of Fatou's Lemma (repost)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Someone recently posted the following question, but it was deleted.  Since it was an interesting question and I didn't know the answer, I'm reposting it here.

The question: is the following limit theorem true?

> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space, $f \in L^{1}(X)$, and $\{f_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq L^{1}(X)$ with $f_{n} \geq 0$ a.e. for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f_{n} \to f$ pointwise a.e.  If $\{f_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded in $L^{1}(X)$, then $f_{n} \to f$ in $L^{1}(X)$ if and only if $\int_{X} f_{n} \, d \mu \to \int_{X} f \, d \mu$.

The answer turns out to be yes.  This isn't completely obvious, and it's interesting since I'm aware of at least one very closely related result in the literature.  (Namely, if $\{\mu_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are finite signed Borel measures on a compact metric space $X$ and $\mu_{n} \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$, then $\|\mu_{n} - \mu\| \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} 0$ if and only if $\|\mu_{n}\|(X) \to \|\mu\|(X)$.)

Answer (score 3):

The result you are asking for is just a special case of a more general result, known as Scheffe's lemma:

> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space. Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, f \in L^1 (X)$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e. in $X$. Then $f_{n} \to f$ in $L^{1}(X)$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X |f_n| d\mu = \int_X |f| d\mu$.

It can be proved in a rather simple way by using Fatou's lemma. Let us prove it:

**Proof**: (=>) It is trivial, since, from Minkowski's inequality, we have
$$\left | \int_X|f_n|d\mu-\int_X|f|d\mu \right |\leqslant \int_X|\,|f_n| -|f|\,| d\mu\leqslant \int_X|f_n -f| d\mu$$

So, if $f_{n} \to f$ in $L^{1}(X)$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X |f_n| d\mu = \int_X |f| d\mu$.

(<=) Note that $|f_n -f|\leqslant |f_n| +|f|$. So, for each $n$, the function $|f_n| +|f| - |f_n -f|$ is non-negative and using Fatou's Lemma, we have
\begin{align} 
2 \int_X|f|d\mu 
&=\int_X \lim\inf(|f_n| +|f| - |f_n -f|)d\mu \leqslant \lim\inf \int_X (|f_n| +|f| - |f_n -f|)d\mu = \\ 
&=\lim\inf \left (\int_X|f_n|d\mu +\int_X|f|d\mu - \int_X|f_n -f|d\mu \right) = \\
&= \left(\lim\inf\int_X|f_n|d\mu\right) +\int_X|f|d\mu - \left(\lim\sup\int_X|f_n -f|d\mu\right)  = \\ 
&=2\int_X|f|d\mu - \left(\lim\sup\int_X|f_n -f|d\mu\right) 
\end{align}
So we have
$$2 \int_X|f|d\mu \leqslant 2\int_X|f|d\mu - \left(\lim\sup\int_X|f_n -f|d\mu\right) $$
Since $f \in L^1 (X)$ , we know that $\int_X|f|d\mu<+\infty$, and so we get
$$\lim\sup\int_X|f_n -f|d\mu \leqslant  0$$
So we can conclude that
$$\lim\int_X|f_n -f|d\mu =  0$$
So, $f_{n} \to f$ in $L^{1}(X)$.

**Remark**: Note that the hypothesis that $\{f_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded in $L^{1}(X)$ is not needed. In fact, it is a consequence of the other hypothesis of the result.

Answer (score 2):

The "only if" direction is immediate so I'll only treat the "if" direction.

A sequence in $L^{1}(X)$ converges if and only if it converges locally in measure, it's uniformly integrable, and it's tight.  This follows from the [Vitali Convergence Theorem](http://math.gmu.edu/%7Edwalnut/teach/Math776/Spring11/776s11lec10_notes.pdf), the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem analogue for $L^{1}$.

**Local convergence in measure:** $\{f_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges locally in measure (i.e. it converges in measure on finite measure sets) since it's pointwise convergent.

**Tightness:** $\{f_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is tight if and only if, for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ and a measurable $A_{\epsilon}$ with $\mu(A_{\epsilon}) < \infty$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{X \setminus A_{\epsilon}} f_{n}(x) \, \mu(dx) < \epsilon.
\end{equation*}

To see this is so, recall that $\{f\}$ is tight so there is an $A_{\epsilon}$ with $\mu(A_{\epsilon}) < \infty$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{X \setminus A_{\epsilon}} f(x) \, \mu(dx) < \epsilon/2.
\end{equation*}
Fatou's Lemma thus gives
\begin{equation*}
\int_{X} f(x) \, \mu(dx) - \epsilon/2 \leq \int_{A_{\epsilon}} f(x) \, \mu(dx) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{X \setminus A_{\epsilon}} f_{n}(x) \, \mu(dx) 
\end{equation*}
and so
\begin{equation*}
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_{\epsilon}} f_{n}(x) \, \mu(dx) \leq \int_{X} f(x) \, \mu(dx) - \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_{X \setminus A_{\epsilon}} f_{n}(x) \, \mu(dx) \leq \epsilon/2.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, there is a $N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ with the desired property.

**Uniform integrability:**  We proceed by contradiction.  $\{f_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is *not* tight if and only if there is a sequence of measurable sets $\{A_{j}\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$, a subsequence $(n_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, and a $\nu > 0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\inf \left\{ \int_{A_{j}} f_{n_{j}}(x) \, \mu(dx) \, \mid \, j \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \geq \nu, \quad \lim_{j \to \infty} \mu(A_{j}) = 0.
\end{equation*}
Passing to a further subsequence, we see that we can assume that $\mu(A_{j}) \leq 2^{-j}$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, hence $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_{j}) < \infty$.  Therefore, by the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, $\mu(\limsup_{j \to \infty} A_{j}) = 0$ (def. of lim-sup of sets can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit)), and an immediate consequence is
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{j \to \infty} f_{n_{j}} \chi_{X \setminus A_{j}} = f \quad \text{a.e.}
\end{equation*}
From this, we see that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{X} f(x) \, \mu(dx) \leq \liminf_{j \to \infty} \int_{X \setminus A_{j}} f_{n_{j}}(x) \, \mu(dx) \leq \int_{X} f(x) \, \mu(dx) - \nu.
\end{equation*}
This contradicts the choice of $\nu > 0$.

(As Ramiro pointed out, the non-negativity of $\{f_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ isn't necessary.  The proof above is readily adapted to that setting.)

Comment: Your answer to your own question is fine, but it is far more complex than it needs to be.  See my answer using Fatou's lemma.

Comment: @Ramiro, long isn't the same as complex. ;)

Comment: I agree that "long isn't the same as complex". But your answer is actually longer and more complex than it need to be. Why is it more complex? Because your answer needed 3 reductions and in the last one it used Vitali Convergence Theorem (which is a more advanced theorem) **and** Fatou's lemma, **while** the same result (actualy a slight generalization) can be easily proved, in a shorter way, simply using Fatou's lemma. Anyway, I don't mean to critize you or your answer. I posted my answer with the idea to help you. I hope you can appreciate my answer.

Comment: I know the proof of Vitali's Theorem. As I said it is a more advanced theorem, as compared to Fatou's lemma, which is a quite basic result . One criteria for good and elegant proofs in Mathematics is exactly not to use more that what is needed to prove the result. The Scheffe's lemma is a nice and direct consequence of Fatou's lemma. No need of Vitali's Convergence Theorem to prove it. And this is what I showed in my answer. I hope you could appreciate it.